# I can't get my Header image to fit to the page content

Tags: html, css, image, header, sizing

I am coding a restaurant website's Home page for a desktop publishing class that I'm in, but I seem to be having some issues (well, multiple issues, but I will start with this one). I can't seem to figure out how to size the header that I exported out of InDesign and coded in Dreamweaver to fit the rest of the content. There is also some white space on the right side that I can't get rid of. I've tried various methods such as adding "overflow: hidden" which just cuts off the content and adds a scroll bar. Would anyone be willing to help me? I'm going mad just trying to figure this out. Thank-you! (my html and css code from Dreamweaver 2019 is posted below)

---

!UPDATE!

Hello,
So here's an update:
I copied and pasted my image from InDesign to Illustrator and exported the image as a jpeg (exporting as html or css did not work). my web page looks great in Dreamweaver, but when I load it into a browser, the images get distorted and cut off. My web page only looks normal when I adjust the size of the entire browser a little. I've googled this issue and am not finding solutions. For some reason, the browser isn't supporting the size and I don't know how to fix it.

[image: incomplete home website]

```
enter code here

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Majesti Banner Bold;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Style the header */
.header {
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
  background-image: url(images/banner.jpg);
  background-size: cover;  
}

/* Increase the font size of the h1 element */
.header h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #41393d;
}

/* Style the navigation bar links */
.navbar a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #d7e4c2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Right-aligned link */
.navbar a.right {
  float: right;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #be1e2d;
  color: #d7e4c2;
}

/* Column container */
.row {  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* Create two unequal columns that sits next to each other */
/* Sidebar/left column */
.side {
  flex: 30%;
  background-color: #41393d;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* adding color to <h2> element */
h2 {
    color: #d7e4c2
}
/*adding color to <h4> element */
h4 {
        color: #d7e4c2;
        text-align: center; 
    }

/* Main column */
.main {   
  flex: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  background-image: url(images/shutterstock_1531950407.jpg);
  background-size: cover; 
}

/* Style the footer */
footer {
  background-color: #be1e2d;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">

</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a>
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="side">
    <h2><center>Welcome!</center></h2>
    <h4><i>TOWN is a high-end fine dining restaurant which serves traditional Chinese cuisine with an added flare. Spanning 4 generations, TOWN prides itself on using the finest organic ingredients available with no added preservatives or MSG, giving you the most authentic experience possible! Part of our mission statement is to bring quality, style, and the wish for good fortune to all of our guests!</i></h4>
    </div>

<div class="main">

  </div>

</div>

<footer>
  <p>Footer</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

[[image: image view in dreamweaver]][1

[image: image view set at normal size in chrome browser]

Answer (score 0):

First off in your `.header` CSS, change the `width` value to `100%;`. You also are going to want to remove the negative margins and change `background-size` to `cover !important`.

Let me know if that works,

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I tried that method and it didn't work, so I started over in Dreamweaver, using the steps provided in w3schools. I also thought that maybe I exported my header image wrong out of Illustrator (it was originally an InDesign doc that I copied and pasted into Illustrator). When I was done, the header looked fine, but the main image was cut off. When I checked it in Chrome, the header was stretched as well as the main image. My page only looks OK when I size the entire browser down a little. Do you know how I can get my web page to fit the whole page? Here is my code:

Comment: Could you please try and replicate your issue on https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I've never used jsfiddle. What do I do once I copy my code in the correct boxes? The yellow dot 'suggestive fixes' do not make sense to me. I apologize, but I am very new to this and am still in the baby steps with coding.

Comment: No worries, once you have your code in jsFiddle, save it, copy the URL and paste it here so I can see where your issue lies.

Comment: OK I saved it to jsfiddle. By the suggestion of my instructor, I deleted the 'header' tags and included 'foreground' to the div tag, but it didn't do a thing :(

Comment: Ok where is the link to it?

Comment: I apologize! Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/kris444/moejuw6a/4/

Comment: No worries, thank you. I have noticed that your closing `</head>` tag is below your `</body>` tag. Can you make sure that your `<head>` tag is closed before starting the `<body>` tag. Let me know if that solves any issues.

Comment: In that case, could you please upload your image to somewhere, copy the link for it and then use that as the background on jsFiddle. As it won't load it from your PC.